# Passing Paramaters from a future class to another class

Tags: apex, future

I am trying to pass some parameters from a future class to the constructor of another class and it is passing nulls values. What is the reason for it? (FYI-The @future class is called from a scheduler class.)

Here is what I am doing by caling the constructor of another class from the @future class:

```
ClassConstructor cc = new ClassConstructor(true,'test','one','yes',(System.isFuture() || System.isScheduled()));
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: So if you log out any of those ClassConstructor parameters they come out as null? Even the booleans? Can you add the class definition to the question?

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason for the values to be null, as Daniel says you're going to have to post more code to get a good answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem is not with future class. I have not properly used variables in the receiving class. I made the parameters of the receiving constructor different from the assigned variables in the receiving constructor and it worked.